# Should 8bit quantization make whisper inference faster on GPU?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, gpu, huggingface

I'm performing whisper inference on huggingface transformers.
`load_in_8bit` quantization is provided by `bitsandbytes`.

Inference on a sample file takes much longer (5x) if whisper-large-v3 is loaded in 8bit mode on NVIDIA T4 gpu. GPU utilization is at 33% in `nvidia-smi`.

Shouldn't quantization improve inference speed on GPU?
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html

similar question:

- https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/enabling-load-in-8bit-makes-inference-much-slower/38596

```py
import torch

from transformers import WhisperFeatureExtractor, WhisperTokenizerFast
from transformers.pipelines.audio_classification import ffmpeg_read

MODEL_NAME = "openai/whisper-large-v3"

tokenizer = WhisperTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
feature_extractor = WhisperFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

model_8bit = AutoModelForSpeechSeq2Seq.from_pretrained(
     "openai/whisper-large-v3",
    device_map='auto',
    load_in_8bit=True)

sample = "sample.mp3" #27s long

with torch.inference_mode():
    with open(sample, "rb") as f:
        inputs = f.read()
        inputs = ffmpeg_read(inputs, feature_extractor.sampling_rate)

        input_features = feature_extractor(inputs, sampling_rate = feature_extractor.sampling_rate, return_tensors='pt')['input_features']

        input_features = torch.tensor(input_features, dtype=torch.float16, device='cuda')

        forced_decoder_ids_output = model_8bit.generate(input_features=input_features, return_timestamps=False)

        out = tokenizer.decode(forced_decoder_ids_output.squeeze())
        print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that the model will be slower with int8 quantization. This is because the quantization adds additional operations to the model's forward pass. You can read more about this in the [int8 quantization paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.07339). You can also find some benchmarks [here](https://huggingface.co/blog/hf-bitsandbytes-integration) that show the same.

The reason to use int8 quantization is to reduce the memory footprint of the model. It allows for loading larger models on less hardware.